# General usefulness of Dense layers for different identification tasks

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, cluster-analysis, word-embedding

I'd like to ask, is it practical to use embeddings and similarity metrics to any form of identification task? If I had a neural network trained to find different objects in a photo, would extracting the fully-connected layers/Dense layers and clustering them be useful?

I've recently found that there is an embeddings projector tool from tensorflow that is very cool and useful. I know that there has been some work in word embeddings and how similar words cluster together. This is the case for faces as well.

Having said that, I want to follow the same methods into analyzing geological sites; can I train a model to create embeddings of the features of a site and use clustering methods to classify?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do that. We can use embeddings for images and visualize the embeddings in the tensorboard.

You can replicate using the fashion mnist embedding example found [here](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist/blob/master/visualization/project_zalando.py) for your use case.